# How to update a column of a DB table when closing the browser in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I am creating a website where I have in DB a table called users with a column status_login, if the user starts session the column updates to 1, if he closes session through the logout button the column updates to 0, this so as not to have two at the same time open sessions.
The problem is that if the user closes the browser then the status_login column does not update and remains at 1, then when logging in again it is not possible since the status is at 1.
I was researching on the subject so what I found is that using a JS function with Ajax I can catch the event when closing the browser, if it works, but the problem is that this event is not compatible with some browsers, or there are problems when using it, for example, in FIREFOX it works fine, but not in Chrome. There are many topics on this but I have not found an updated or helpful answer.
Do you have any idea how to solve this problem? On the banks page, if you close the browser, is the session closed, how is this possible? Has anyone already had the same problem?

Comment: You cannot reliably have the browser fire an event when the user "leaves" via closing the tab/browser. A better idea would be to change from an `online: yes/no` to `last_activity: [timestamp]` and consider the user to be "online" if their `last_activity` timestamp is within the last X seconds/minutes/etc.

Comment: This sounds good, but does it affect if the user is watching a 1 hour video and has no activity? does not close session?

Comment: 1.0 Add a time column( e.g. status_update )  to your db table. 2.0 Use Ajax to update this column with current time every 1 min. 3.0 Include a code at the top of all your pages which update the status_login column to 0 for any row where the TIMESTAMPDIFF is greater than 1 min

Comment: What hans said, but a word of caution: Have your ajax code detect if the page is in focus or not. Former workplace had a similar solution that didn't and the number of pings from people leaving tabs open in the background for days/weeks was essentially causing us to DDoS ourselves.

Comment: Specifically with regard to "On the banks page, if you close the browser, is the session closed, how is this possible?" you can set a cookie without a defined lifetime, which is deleted when the browser/tab is closed. Subsequent visits to the site might treat you as logged out, but the only for the reason that you're missing that cookie that identifies you as a "logged-in" user, not because the site actually processed a "logout".

Answer (score 0):

I think you try to do get user online time. in that case this not good idea but i think it's work.
you can time to time request send on browser using java script (AJEX) and in server side you can update is online time on db. if browser send request time gap greater than with last update time it mean user go off line.

previously i have similar problem and i solve it like this idea.